# Different link paths for view nodes

Tags: views, redirection

I am using Drupal 7 and I have a block view in my home page. This block view selects nodes from two different content types. Only the titles from these nodes are appearing in the block view. By clicking on these titles I want to redirect in two different pages, based on the content type each view node belongs.

e.g For the view node with title : "Meeting on 3th September", I want to redirect on ".../drupal/meetings" page,but for the view node with title "Announcement of program" I want to redirect on ".../drupal/news" page

What is the way for redirection from view nodes to different links according the content type of the view nodes?

Thank you.

Comment: You may create path of the view & call that path in title.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the previous problem as follows:

1.In my block view I added the field "Type", and i clicked the option "Exclude from Display"

2.In the field "Title" of the view, I disabled the option "Link this field to the original piece of content" and i rewrote the title with the rule: [type].

3.I added a redirection rule from each type to the corresponding link

Answer (score 0):

What are the names of the Content Types that you have?

If your Content types are of **Meetings** & **News**.

You could possibly Rewrite the link on the `[node_title]` field using the Content type field. This would end up being `/drupal/[content_type]`